# Where can I find solutions to exercises in "A Handbook of Statistical Analysis Using R"?

Tags: r, references

I really hope this isn't a repeat post because I have looked around a good bit. I find myself getting stuck on a few questions here and there in HSAUR as I feel the exercises aren't always a logical extensions of the material in the book. I tend to find my way through, but not always, and when I do I believe it is often sub-optimal.

Does that book have its solutions anywhere? They'd be a great help for me.

Comment: This is a really good book. But I don't think there is any solution available. There is another similar book "The Basics of S-PLUS" by Andreas Krause Melvin Olson that can be considered as an "introduction to R". It has many exercises with detailed solutions.

Comment: For the vexing questions, you should just rephrase and ask it as a question here on stackexchange.

Comment: This question seems on-topic to me, as a reference-request.